# HTML: input file dies when moving to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to get an input file to stay 'alive' untill the next page, but I haven't had any success. Basically what I have is:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" id="input1" />`
```

These input files will be videos, which I would like to play, but on the next page.

I get a playable src-url via

```
window.URL.createObjectURL($("#input1")[0].files[0])
```

which works on that page. I then store that URL in sessionStorage and retrieve it on the next page, but the URL no longer points to a valid file. I understand why this is happening, but is there any way to access that same file on the next page?

- I can't put the whole video file in sessionStorage, because this will be too big.
- An alternative would be to stay on the same page, but I think this will make my code much uglier? Except maybe if there is a solution to this, I would still like seperate HTML files and not all the HTML-code in javascript files

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I saw a similar question to this, and you cannot get a file on another page. If this were the case, a server could just guess some url and then have a file of a user, which he probably doesn't want the server to have. You second solution seems the best in this case. You can easily have html code in separate files and then load certain elements(only body or whatever) via javascript ajax.

Comment: @frederik-witte Alright, I was kind of hoping there would be an exception for files from the same domain. I will look into the second option. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: How is opened the next page?

Comment: @a-wolff with `<button onclick="window.location.href='nextpage.html'">Continue</button>`